# jquery disables all the checkbox in a table

Tags: jquery

How can I disable only a single check box in a table row? I have my for condition in a phtml file. My html has one `td` for my checkbox, but if I click on one check box it disables all the checkboxes in a table. Below is my for loop with check box.

```
<?php    
    foreach($this->rows as $record)
    {         
        echo "<tr>";       
        echo "<td >". $record['firstname'] . "</td>";      
        echo "<td>".$record['advicetoowners'] . "</td>";        
        echo"<td>".$record['customdata'] . " <br /> ".$record['reservation'."</td>"; 
        ?>

        <td class='stylecontent'width='2' >
            <input type="checkbox" name="seen" value="" class='chkAll'/>
        </td>     
        <?php
    }          
?>
```

My jQuery is:

```
$('.chkAll').change(function() {
    // This disables all the check box in a table.How to make it to disable only one
    $('input:checkbox').attr('disabled', this.checked); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this to

```
 $('.chkAll').change(function() {
        $('input:checkbox').attr('disabled', this.checked); 
 });
```

this

```
 $('.chkAll').change(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', this.checked); 
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.chkAll').change(function() {
        $(this).attr('disabled', this.checked); 
    });
```